# SerialPort.Write() take a relatively long time to execute

Tags: c#, serial-port

The function `mySerialPort.Write("Hello")` takes a full millisecond to execute. I have added a Stopwatch to my code which helps me understand the execution time. Is there any way the program could execute this faster? Can the issue be related to the serial port driver? I am using a USB to Serial converter cable. Baud Rate = 115200 Parity = None Data Bits = 8 Stop Bits = One If I replace the `mySerialPort.Write("Hello")` line with an empty for loop which runs 10000 times, it executes almost instantly. Therefore if someone could help me achieve a similar speed for the execution of `mySerialPort.Write("Hello")` it will be of immense help. Thanks in advance.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();                        
    mySerialPort.Write("Hello");                          
    stopWatch.Stop();
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    textBox2.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
}
```

Comment: What speed are you expecting it to execute at? Even with no overhead, the theoretical best is 0.35 milliseconds. Also, why compare the time it takes to an empty loop? It's surely not surprising that it takes the computer longer to do something than it does to do nothing.

Comment: You might consider doing asynchronously.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your response. My application requires that I execute mySerialPort.Write() in the fastest way possible. Can you suggest how to achieve the theoretical best time of 0.35 milliseconds?

Comment: @Guclu I already tried that. The execution time of mySerialPort.Write() remains same.

Comment: Behind most any quirky benchmark result is broken benchmark code.  If it actually takes a millisecond then your textBox2 still displays "00:00:00.00".  So there isn't any possible way you can actually *see* that it takes a millisecond.